# Package Layers to Geopackage stripping layers of all data using QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-processing, geopackage

I am having a strange issue with packaging temporary layers to a geopackage and would like to try and figure out whether I am doing something wrong before I file a bug report.

I have about 180 points layers, extracted from a larger points layer, which I have tried to save into a geopackage using the 'package layers' algorithm.

It takes a while and at first appears to have been successful. The layers all appear within the geopackage in the Browser Panel and when I open the attribute table of a layer from the Browser Panel it looks as it should.

However, when I drag a layer onto the canvas it is devoid of any data. Then when I open the attribute table of any of the layers in the Browser Panel they are also devoid of data.

Does anyone have any idea what may be going on or what I could be doing wrong?

I have done this before with the same data set and it worked fine.
The larger point file is a .csv which I have added as delimited text and then packaged into the geopackage.

I am using QGIS 3.32 on Kubuntu Linux. I tried recreating the issue on my Windows 10 partition but QGIS hangs when running my script to extract the smaller layers from the larger one.

Here is the python script I am using to extract the smaller layers from the larger, just in case that could be the issue.

```
from qgis.core import QgsVectorLayer, QgsProject, QgsFeature, QgsFeatureRequest


input_layer_name = 'processed_data'

input_layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName(input_layer_name)[0]

bemerkung_field_index = input_layer.fields().indexFromName('bemerkung')

grouped_features = {}

for feature in input_layer.getFeatures():
    bemerkung_value = feature.attributes()[bemerkung_field_index]
    
    if str(bemerkung_value).startswith('F'):
        if bemerkung_value not in grouped_features:
            grouped_features[bemerkung_value] = []
        grouped_features[bemerkung_value].append(feature)

for bemerkung_value, features in grouped_features.items():
    # Convert the QVariant to a string for the layer name
    layer_name = str(bemerkung_value)
    
    new_layer = QgsVectorLayer(
        'Point?crs=' + input_layer.crs().authid(),
        layer_name,
        'memory'
    )
    
    new_layer.dataProvider().addAttributes(input_layer.fields())
    new_layer.updateFields()
    
    new_layer.startEditing()
    for feature in features:
        new_feature = QgsFeature(new_layer.fields())
        new_feature.setGeometry(feature.geometry())
        new_feature.setAttributes(feature.attributes())
        new_layer.addFeature(new_feature)
    new_layer.commitChanges()
    
    QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(new_layer)

iface.layerTreeView().refreshLayerSymbology(input_layer.id())

QgsProject.instance().write()
```